# Need CloudFront with lambda@edge to serve S3 bucket while using Amlify

Tags: aws-amplify, aws-amplify-cli

I was wondering how I can use Amplify to create Cloudfront to serve dynamic images (for users) in S3 bucket.  Amplify hosting does not work since it is for static content.  Also, I will need to have couple Lambda@edge.

Is this something that can be done with Amplify CLI.
Is there another way to do this while keeping my Amplify project.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

It's not supported by amplify cli (yet).
See here: https://github.com/aws-amplify/amplify-cli/issues/1910

But you can setup cloudfront from *AWS Web Console* and then "connect" to your amplify cli added S3 bucket (amplify storage category) and lambdas (created with *amplify add funcion*)